# LaTeX section highlighting in vim

Tags: vim, latex, syntax-highlighting, tex

In LaTeX, a section looks like:

```
\section{Section Title}
```

I would like to highlight such sections, or section titles. I tried to put the following in `~/.vim/bundle/latexrc/after/syntax/tex.vim`:

```
syn match texSectioning "\\section\>" skipwhite nextgroup=texSectioningTitle
syn region texSectioningTitle       contained matchgroup=Delimiter start='{'    end='}' contains=@texSectioningGroup
syn cluster texSectioningGroup      contains=texMatcher,texComment,texDelimiter
```

(Note that this kind of syntax is not handled by the default `tex.vim` syntax file. It only defines "section zones", which are pretty much worthless for me.)

I then define the following in my color scheme:

```
hi texSectioning gui=bold guifg=red
```

And nothing happens; that is, section titles do not appear in red in my LaTeX code (even after I reloaded the file completely).

I am totally confused as to how vim's syntax work, and how to debug it.

**Edit**
Some more information: it sometimes works and sometimes not. *Completely unpredictable*. What could be the problem? Pathogen? Something else? I'm completely puzzled.

Comment: Could you perhaps describe what highlighting you would like to achieve, and how it differs from the default TeX highlighting?

Comment: It's in the post: *I would like to highlight such sections, or section titles.*. This is not covered by the standard `tex.vim` syntax file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer: the tex.vim divides the text in zones, in which the syntax must be *explicitly* allowed. The key element is that command:

```
syn cluster texChapterGroup contains=@texSectioningGroup
```

This says to vim that inside a `texChapterGroup`, the syntax cluster `texSectioningGroup` is allowed. The next thing to do is simply to define that cluster as usual.

Another detail is that the region `texSectioningTitle` must be `contained`, otherwise it will match arbitrary pairs of `{}` in LaTeX.

So a complete solution goes like this:

```
syn match texSectioningCommand '\\section\>' skipwhite     nextgroup=texSectioningTitle contains=@texSectioningGroup
syn region texSectioningTitle        start='{'  end='}' contained
syn cluster texSectioningGroup contains=texSectioningCommand
syn cluster texChapterGroup contains=@texSectioningGroup
```

**Edit** Here is why the behaviour was apparently unpredictable: vim does not read the entire file to figure out the syntax. So in a big enough chapter, my section syntax would work because vim did not go far enough to see it was in a chapter zone.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the new syntax items `texSectioning`, `texSectioningTitle` and `texSectioningGroup`, but you have not linked them to a highlighting group, so Vim doesn't know how to display them. Try adding these lines:

```
hi def link texSectioning Statement
hi def link texSectioningTitle String
hi def link texSectioningGroup Comment
```

The `Statement`, `String` and `Comment` colourings are defining by the colourscheme you are using. These are just examples: you can replace them with any group defined in the colourscheme file.

Answer (score 0):

Just to update the information to highlight section easily. Using containedin means that all the other syntax matches contains this new syntax match. Then just define the color you want.

```
syn match texSectioningCommand '\\section\>' containedin=ALLBUT,texComment
hi texSectioningCommand guifg=#ec5f67 ctermfg=203
```

Alternatively, a simple new syntax match could be added to the texFoldGroup in order to be evaluated inside the the block document.

```
syn match texSectioningCommand '\\section\>'
syn cluster texFoldGroup add=texSectioningCommand
hi texSectioningCommand guifg=#ec5f67 ctermfg=203
```